# Set "text field" trait to a customized iOS component

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

I made a customized text input component like this. It works as a text input. How should I set its `accessibilityTraits` to `text field` so that VoiceOver would recognize it. I searched for the available [accessibilityTraits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility/accessibility_traits) but does not find one.

[image: Customized text input]